# Sennheiser 2000 survey

Tags: wireless

Anybody using Sennheiser 2000 Series on location? I´m highly interested on how this wireless system works in the battle field. I also would love to hear how do they work on the stage, is it a big quality difference with a lectro system sound?
Thanks,